# Type parameter 'T' must be a class type

Tags: delphi

I am writing a small helper class for REST operations. One of my main goals is to provide automatic casting from the body response in JSON to a specific object using generics.

This is how one of the functions look in the helper class:

```
function RESTServiceCallHelper.ExecuteAsObject<TObj>(resource: string): TObj;
var
 RestRequest: TRESTRequest;
 obj: TObj;
begin
  PrepareRequest(RestRequest, resource);
  RestRequest.Execute;
  obj := TJson.JsonToObject<TObj>(RestRequest.Response.Content);
  result:=obj;
end;
```

And here is how I am trying to use it:

type

```
   TPartnerCreditInfo   = class
      FlCreditClassDesc: string;
      FCppID: string;
      FCreditClass: string;
      FCreditClassDesc: string;
      FCreditLimit_CurrencyCode: string;
      FCreditLimit: double;
      FAmountBalance: double;
      FAmountBalance_CurrencyCode: string;
      FAmountBalanceLast: double;
      FAmountBalanceLast_CurrencyCode: string;
   end;

procedure TModuleX.CallAPIS;
var
  lRESTHelper : TrpRESTServiceCallHelper;
  pc: TPartnerCreditInfo;
begin
  lRESTHelper:= TrpRESTServiceCallHelper.Create('https://mydomain/api');
  lRESTHelper.AddQueryStringParam('param1','paramvalue');

  pc:=lRESTHelper.ExecuteAsObject<TPartnerCreditInfo>('resource');
  showmessage(pc.FCppID);
end;
```

The issue I am facing is this at compilation time:

```
obj := TJson.JsonToObject<TObj>(RestRequest.Response.Content);
[dcc32 Error] RESTServiceCallObj.pas(99): E2511 Type parameter 'T' must be a class type
```

According to the documentation the T parameter for JsonToObject function must be a class and TPartnerCreditInfo is a class too. Why is TPartnerCreditInfo not being recognized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `T` Generic parameter of [`TJson.JsonToObject()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Json.TJson.JsonToObject) has been marked with the [`class` and `constructor` constraints](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics).  As such, the `TObj` Generic parameter of your `ExecuteAsObject()` function needs to be marked with the same constraints:

```pascal
function ExecuteAsObject<TObj: class, constructor>(resource: string): TObj;
```

Those constraints inform the compiler that `T`/`TObj` are *required* to be a class type that has a parameterless `Create()` constructor, which is what allows `JsonToObject()` to create a new object instance of the type passed to `T`/`TObj`.